# How to print object's element?

Tags: rust

I have this small program in rust, not in a cargo project.

```rs
use std::process::Command;
fn main() {
    let result= Command::new("git").arg("status").output().expect("Ok");
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

but after building and running it I get

```bash
Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(0)), stdout: "On branch main\nYour branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.\n\nUntracked files:\n  (use \"git add <file>...\" to include in what will be committed)\n\tbasics/guessing_game/\n\tcmdtest\n\tcmdtest.rs\n\nnothing added to commit but untracked files present (use \"git add\" to track)\n", stderr: "" }
```

If I try:

```rs
use std::process::Command;
fn main() {
    let result= Command::new("git").arg("status").output().expect("Ok");
    println!("{:?}", result.stdout);
}
```

I get

```bash
[79, 110, 32, 98, 114, 97, 110, 99, 104, 32, 109, 97, 105, 110, 10, 89, 111, 117, 114, 32, 98, 114, 97, 110, 99, 104, 32, 105, 115, 32, 117, 112, 32, 116, 111, 32, 100, 97, 116, 101, 32, 119, 105, 116, 104, 32, 39, 111, 114, 105, 103, 105, 110, 47, 109, 97, 105, 110, 39, 46, 10, 10, 85, 110, 116, 114, 97, 99, 107, 101, 100, 32, 102, 105, 108, 101, 115, 58, 10, 32, 32, 40, 117, 115, 101, 32, 34, 103, 105, 116, 32, 97, 100, 100, 32, 60, 102, 105, 108, 101, 62, 46, 46, 46, 34, 32, 116, 111, 32, 105, 110, 99, 108, 117, 100, 101, 32, 105, 110, 32, 119...
```

How can I print the string inside stdout and not numbers, in a user friendly format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

stdout may not be valid unicode, in which case you cannot print it. If you're sure it will be (which is probably the case with git), you can use [`String::from_utf8().unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8):

```rust
fn main() {
    let result = Command::new("git").arg("status").output().expect("Ok");
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8(result.stdout).unwrap());
}
```

If you don't know, you can either check the `Result` `from_utf8()` returns, or use [`String::from_utf8_lossy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy) to turn invalid characters into [`U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/char/constant.REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER.html) �:

```rust
fn main() {
    let result = Command::new("git").arg("status").output().expect("Ok");
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&result.stdout));
}
```